# Wake-on-LAN over the Internet connection using C++

Tags: c++, winapi, wake-on-lan

I'm coding using C++ WinAPIs for Windows and I was wondering if it's possible to implement the Wake-On-LAN functionality for a client computer (running Windows 7) via an Internet connection and not just LAN?

Comment: Good luck finding a router that doesn't block WOL requests from outside the LAN.  You can thank the Smurf DoS attack for that.

Comment: Yeah, I see that it's virtually impossible.... ((

Answer (score 0):

LogMeIn.com has a "Wake On LAN" feature that looks like it does this - I have no idea if it works, or how it works.

If I were doing this, I would:

1) have a web server (on the same LAN as your PC) listening for "Wake on LAN" requests,

2) have the web server issue the request.

IMHO...

PS:

You could always try installing LogMeIn (it's free), and see if it does what you need:

http://www.logmein.com

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how knowing that this commercial product works on my system will help me? I need to be able to do it in my code...

Comment: @ahmd0 it's called reverse engineering.